# R - grouped bar plot percentage

Tags: r, percentage

I would like to transform the graph I have, into a graph that presents the same information, but in percentages, per group. So the bars ABC at '1' have to add up to 100%, bars ABC at '2' add up to 100%, etc, etc. I don't want them stacked though, I like the look of the grouped bar plots.

Hope you can help!

```
TableAltPerfBar<-subset(TableAltPerf, EntranceType >1)
TableAltPerfBar$EntranceType[TableAltPerfBar$EntranceType==3]<-5
counts <- table(TableAltPerfBar$EntranceType, TableAltPerfBar$Day)
barplot(counts, main="Entrances",
    xlab="Days", ylab="Number of entrances", col=c("green","darkblue", "red"),
    legend = c("A", "B", "C"), beside=TRUE)
```

Comment: Look at `prop.table` as a way to create `counts`

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.